# Java class inheritance of variables and methods

Tags: java, class

```
class Machine {
    int info1 = 7;      
    public void show(){
        System.out.println(info1);
    }
}

class Camera extends Machine {
     int info1 = 13;
}

public class Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Machine combo = new Camera();
        combo.show();
    }
}
```

From my understanding, I've created an Object called `combo` by instantiating the class of `Camera`, but am using the variable type of `Machine`, which is the superclass of `Camera`.

Now, since I'm creating an `Object` of `Camera`, I expect the method `show()` to print 13, but this code instead prints 7, as declared in the superclass `Machine`.  I realize that the variable type of Machine confers the reference variable `combo` the method `show()`, but shouldn't the value return 13 since the Object itself is an instance of `Camera`?  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It prints 7 because the method `show` is not in the scope of the `Camera` class.

Comment: you are shadowing the `info1` field. (a thing that Java should really not let you do in the first place)

Comment: @RyanJ: your comment is misleading. It is not a matter of the scope of `show`.

Comment: @njzk2 Maybe, but his question was `why does 13 not print?` You can answer that question in two ways: I chose to look at it from one perspective.

Comment: There is one simple rule: "fields are not polymorphic" (late binding is not involved for them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two variables called `info1` in this case - the variable in the subclass will not override the variable in the superclass, it will The `show` method prints the one that belongs to `Machine`.

The variable `info1` declared in the subclass is said to hide the variable declared in the parent class, as explained in [section 8.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3):

> If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to *hide* any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class.

Comment: why did they do that?

Comment: @njzk2 same reason they let you use the same variable names in method parameters as instance fields. If you are explicit about how you use your variables, you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: @njzk2 Why would you want to allow for variable overriding? :)

Comment: @manouti: not variable overriding, just no compile this kind of field hiding. It can only lead to errors.

Answer (score 2):

The `info1` variable in `Camera` isn't overloading the `info1` variable in `Machine`, but rather is [hiding it.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

In this case the `show()` method can only see the `info1` which is declared in its own class.  Methods on `Machine` can't access fields which exist in sub-classes.

If you want to be able to change the value in a sub-class, you need to set it in a constructor like so:

```
class Camera extends Machine {
    public Camera() {
        super.info1 = 13;
    }
}
```

In this case, you are explicitly referencing the `info1` in `Machine` and changing its value.

Comment: Though this doesn't detract from the concept of the answer, it would be worth noting that `info1` needs `protected` or `public` access to be set in such a manner. Usage of a setter function would be required otherwise.

Comment: @RyanJ True, but if `info1` were `private` then the hiding wouldn't cause as much confusion, since nobody would expect it to be overloadable in the first place. ;-)

Comment: Agreed, just thought I would mention it since the OP shows the declaration and how it's implicitly declared private. :)

Answer (score 1):

As @manouti mentioned `info1` are two different variables in each class (they are not overridden). However you could achieve the "required" functionality, without introducing a new variable by changing `Camera` class like this:

```
class Machine {
    int info1 = 7;

    public void show(){
        System.out.println(info1);
    }
}

class Camera extends Machine {

    public Camera() {
        info1 = 13;
    }

}
```